# How to specify downstream Pipeline job in parent Jenkins Pipeline job without triggering it?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline job named "Pipeline1"(scripted pipeline and not a freestyle job) which will pass parameters to a downstream job "Pipeline2" (another Pipeline job, not freestyle job) and trigger it. This is the command I used:

**build job: "Pipeline2", parameters: [string(name: 'BUILD_VERSION', value: "${BUILD_VERSION}")]**

I don't want the downstream job to be triggered by the parent job. Instead, I just want the parameters to be passed to Pipeline2 so it can be triggered manually later. Has anyone done this? Can you share some ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot pass parameters without triggering job. This is how Jenkins works.

Comment: In a freestyle job, it is still possible, right. here is a screenshot: